# Java 6 language compared with C# 3.0 language

Tags: c#, java, comparison

There exists a very good talk about C# vs. Java where H.Mössenböck compares the two languages. That's from 2003, C# 2.0 compared with Java 1.5.

Can be found in German here: http://dotnet.jku.at/

What good resources exist, where actual language versions are compared?
Or maybe post a comparison right here?

My interests are:

**Advantages/Disadvantages of the Java 6 language (features, syntactic sugar, ..) compared with C# 3.0 language.**

*Current IDE, VM, CLR and current Framework capabilities would exceed this question...*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 6 didn't have any *language* improvements over Java 5 - where as C# 3 had a [ton of new features](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide3.aspx). Many, but not all, of the C# 3 improvements [can still be used when targeting .NET 2.0](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx).

Java 7 has had a lot of [*proposals* for new language features](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7), but it's not clear which features will actually get in there. [C# 4](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfuture) will have significant new features, but it'll be a more incremental change than the one between 2 and 3.